# QueryBuilder with Join and Order By?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, java-8

I have this query code in my application:

```
@Override
public MyParameter loadMyParameterSetByVersion(Long version) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT mp FROM MyParameter mp ");
    sb.append("INNER JOIN FETCH mp.priceParametersGood good ");
    sb.append("WHERE mp.objId = :version ");
    sb.append("ORDER BY good.isBc, good.isGd, good.priceFrom");

    QueryBuilder builder = createQueryBuilder(sb.toString());
    builder.addParameter("version", version);

    List<MyParameter> result = executeQuery(builder.createQuery());
    if (result.size() > 0) {
        return result.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I did not write this method, I just added the ORDER BY condition, because it's needed right now. My problem is, the results are still not sorted that way. Do I need to rewrite this? If yes, what should I use to make it work?

I tried this query in my Oracle DB and there the results are sorted, so I assume it's something with this Query.

Comment: I think you need to useOrdering order = QueryBuilder.desc( "col" ); QueryBuilder.select().all().from( table.tableName() ).where( cName ).orderBy( order );
It may be adding a orderby for you when there is no orderby added: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1438

Comment: Oh my god :O Can you please somehow add this to my query so I can see how exactly? In one answer for example :)

Comment: Can you add the import for QueryBuilder ? I assume datastax.

Answer (score 0):

[I think a orderby is added for you when no orderBy() is added](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1438).
So this essentially QueryBuilder will override your orderby that is in the string by adding yet another order by.

Instead of having a hard coded string as the SQL, you should use the DSL syntax that QueryBuilder offers you.

Using some code I found [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Ordering) you will see that you are using QueryBuilder in the wrong way and the original code should be re-written.

You code should look more the the article.

```
Statement statement = QueryBuilder.select().all().from( table.tableName() ).where( cName ).and( cBtm ).and( cTop ).orderBy( order );

final Iterator<Row> iter = session.execute( statement ).iterator();
for (Row row : iter ){
...
}
```